# amazon-ecr-credential-helper installation on Centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am trying to setup amazon-ecr-credential-helper on centos 7 machine. Used this document provided by aws as reference : https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper

Can someone please help?

Comment: If yuo need to use the ECR credential helper with Jenkins, you should mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

AWS push their version of Centos so they are not interested in making this available. The same RPM might work but the manual install process is easy enough.

Based on this [this blog](https://www.mskarademir.com/install-aws-ecr-credential-helper-on-centos/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=install-aws-ecr-credential-helper-on-centos)

Install Go and git

```
yum install -y wget git
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Install the helper and move it into the path

```
go get -u github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/ecr-login/cli/docker-credential-ecr-login
cp /root/go/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/bin
```

Config, please adjust as needed. Note the region is also in the `config.json` file

```
mkdir ~/.aws/
cat > ~/.aws/credentials << EOF
[default]
region = us-west-1
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxx
EOF

mkdir ~/.docker/
cat > ~/.docker/config.json << EOF
{
    "credHelpers": {
        "xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
}
EOF
```

Then your pull should work with

```
docker pull xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/arkis_nginx:latest
```

Comment: I tried using these steps but whats happening is that i am able to pull/push image from ecr using shell but not from jenkins.

Comment: I am getting following error:

`at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:150)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)`

Comment: But if I generate and add ecr authentication key to .docker/config.json and delete the above config, job runs successfully in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone and build manually.

First install wget and git:

```
yum install -y wget git
```

Then install go lang:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Add go lang to path, add following line to end of /etc/profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Then run it to reload path:

```
source /etc/profile
```

Finally clone the aws credentials helper, build it and copy to /usr/local/bin:

```
git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper.git
cd amazon-ecr-credential-helper
make docker
sudo cp amazon-ecr-credential-helper/bin/local/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you mention Jenkins. If that is your use case, note that the `Pipeline: AWS Steps` plugin provides an `ecrLogin()` which you could use in a `Jenkinsfile` as follows, by-passing the need to install the ECR Credential Helper:

```
environment {
  credentials = 'my-credentials'
  registry = 'https://123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
  region = 'us-west-1'
  dockerImage = ''
}

stage('Create image') {
  steps{
    script {
      dockerImage = docker.build('my-image', '--no-cache .')
    }
  }
}

stage('Push image to repository') {
  steps {
    script {
      withAWS(credentials: credentials, region: region) {
        sh ecrLogin() 
        docker.withRegistry( registry ) {
          dockerImage.push()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```